# Php parsed in a html document doesn't run

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have parsed `PHP` within my `HTML` document  and have saved it to the root directory of my wamp by the name `helloworld` and by the extension HTML but whenever I access that web page through my web browser using the URL:

> http://localhost/helloworld.html.....

my browser just shows a blank screen.Why is this happening plz help? (Please note that I always keep the `HTTP` server and the database server of my wamp running while I do this)

Comment: Try the extension .php instead of .html

Comment: Ya when I do that then its working properly.... But I wanted to parse php with my html documents what do I do then...?

Comment: Please Refer this SO answer: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939309/php-files-not-working-when-using-bootstrap/44939607#44939607)

Answer (score 2):

I think You simply missing the point:

To run a PHP file with `WAMP` you need to follow this basic step:

---

1. Now Simply Create your project folder. i.e `test_project`
   `WAMP/WWW/test_project`
2. Now Put Your `helloworld.html` file inside the project folder and change the extension to `.php`
3. Now to open this `helloworld.php` you can go to your browser and type `localhost/test_project/helloworld.php`. This will automatically run your file.

And if you are keen to use it this way then you should do this. 
you can use PHP code inside .html files, But you need to config the web server. In Apache you can config like this:

```
# Interpret both .php & .html as PHP:
AddHandler php5-script .php .html
```

As reference look this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856825/what-does-htaccess-with-line-addhandler-php5-script-php-do#7856841)

Answer (score -1):

To execute PHP scripts, you have to rename your file to .PHP extension and make sure it's run by a webserver.

Comment: If you want to parse PHP BUT keep the HTML extension, you have to do some rewrite rules on your webserver config, like .htaccess on Apache or your nginx config

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have a `http://anyurl/page.html` that parses `PHP-Code` you can add a Rewrite Rule (Mod Rewrite) like this in your `.htaccess-File`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Keep in Mind that the Files have to be stored as `.php-Files` and that these are only camouflaged `PHP-Files` and displayed as `HTML-Files` in your Browser.